# Let $n=2047$. Using the fact that $3^{88} \equiv 1\pmod {n}, 3^{55} \equiv 1565\pmod {n}.$ Show that n is a composite number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n=2047$.

Using the fact that $$3^{88} \equiv 1\pmod {n}, 3^{55} \equiv 1565\pmod {n}.$$ Show that n is a composite number.

This is a question on a past exam that I find difficulty to answer. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

If $n$ is prime, then

$3^{GCD(88,n-1)}\equiv 3^{22}\equiv 1\pmod n,3^{11}\equiv \pm 1 \pmod n,3^{55}\equiv \pm 1\neq 1565 \pmod n$

Comment: This is the only answer so far that uses the $3^{55}$ related fact.

Answer (score 2):

An answer from group theory: if $\;n=2047\;$ is prime, then $\;\Bbb F_n^*\;$ is a (cyclic) group, so by Lagrange's theorem

$$3^{88}=1\pmod n\implies 88\mid |\Bbb F_n^*|=n-1=2046$$

But, of course, it is false that $\;88\mid 2046\;$...for example, it's easy to see that $\;2046=2\pmod 4\;$ , whereas $\;88=0\pmod 4\;$ .

Comment: $88$ need not $\mid n-1,$ because $88$ maybe not the order, but just a  multiple of the order.

Comment: @Hecke, it should be $($ord$_{2047}3,88)$ must divide $88,$ right?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Yep

Answer (score 1):

A quick hint (that should be a comment): If $n$ is prime, then $x^{n}=x \pmod{n}$ for all $x$.